# ERROR: Youtube link inside html text inside react native app

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, webview, html-rendering

I've some problem with some html code to render inside my app.

I'm fetching it and saving the html code inside this.state.text_ :

```
return fetch('https://www.rallyssimo.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/'+_links)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState(
          {
            text_: responseJson.content.rendered,
          },
          function() {}
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

If i print it inside a `<Text>` tab it appears correctly (whit html tags obviously).

But when I try to render it with react-native-html-render library, if there's a tag for a youtube video, i got an error: `invariant violation: WebView has been removed from react native... etc..."`.

```
<HTML html={this.state.text_} />
```

I'm not using WebView in my code, so I think it's used in the react-native-html-render library.

I've also tried to use react-native-webview library to render the html code

```
<WebView
  source={{ html: this.state.text_ }}
/>
```

but I obtained a white screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing you can do about this at the moment, webView has been removed from `react-native` while the `react-native-html-render` library has yet to be updated. The PR with a fix has been merged into master, and in the following days it will be tested and published on npm.

It is an open issue: https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html/issues/265

As a temporary fix while you wait for an update of the pkg, you can

- Change version of the pkg to a PR with a fix

`"react-native-render-html": "^4.1.2"`

to

`"react-native-render-html": "git+https://github.com/chr314/react-native-render-html.git"`

- Manually install it

  npm install --save react-native-webview react-native link react-native-webview

then in the plugin folder, go to `src/HTMLRenderers.js`, remove WebView in {..} 'react-native';
and add this line
`import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';`

Comment: thanks! i've tried it on my own and it works! (it's pretty bad but I can almost load the page ':D).